# "command not found" in ZSH script

Tags: bash, alias, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to run this script by typing `~/scripts/recomposeUi.zsh` but am receiving the following error when doing so:

`/Users/me/scripts/recomposeUi.zsh:2: command not found: dcrs`

Here is my script, **recomposeUi.zsh:**

```
#!/bin/zsh
cd ~/myProject/ && npm run build && docker build -t wm . && cd ~/projectTwo/ && dcrs && cd ~/myProject/
```

Here is my **.zshrc:**

```
alias dcd='docker-compose down'
alias dcu='docker-compose up -d'
alias dcp='docker-compose pull'
alias dcrs='dcd && dcp; dcu'
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.zshrc` is executed in interactive shell.

Shell for script isn't interactive.

Try to move your aliases to `.zshenv` (executed always) or add to head of your script command `source ~/.zshrc` (manually read)